# Image Processing Matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

In order to remove most of the unwanted edges, I need to connect components in the image and filter out the components that do not have exactly one hole based on their Euler number.

I know that I have to use image processing functions `bwconncomp` and `regionprops` but I don't have experience with them.

This is my code:

```
rgb=imread('2whgyzr.jpg');
gray_scale = rgb2gray(rgb);
BW3 = edge(gray_scale,'canny',[],1);
```

and this is the image:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/2whgyzr/6]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job if I understand your question correct:

```
filtered = false(size(BW3));
CC = bwconncomp(BW3);
CC_props = regionprops(CC,'EulerNumber');

for cc_idx = 1:length(CC.PixelIdxList)
   if(CC_props(cc_idx).EulerNumber == 0)
       pixels = CC.PixelIdxList{cc_idx};
       filtered(pixels) = true;
   end
end

imshow(filtered)
```

[image]